# Sentencia SQL para saber si el usuario y contraseña ingresados en el login son iguales a los guardados en mi base de datos, programa en Java

Tags: java, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla "usuario" de la base de datos habrá un registro siempre con un usuario y contraseña para poder iniciar sesión por primera vez.

Debo saber si el usuario y contraseña ingresados son iguales a los que están guardados en mi base de datos. También, deseo que en lugar de que me hale el id_perfil tipo INT, me hale el nombre del perfil tipo String.

Todos los datos que pido, los mostraré en labels text para fines de visualización nada mas. Para mostrar: Usuario conectado: nombre,, user, pass, etc..

No entiendo bien las sentencias SQL, es mi segunda vez trabajando con ellas y necesito ayuda para saber si esta correcto.

Código:

```
public boolean login(String usuario, String contrasena) {
        Dato_login d_lgn = new Dato_login();
        boolean resultado = false;

        sSQL = "SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.contrasena, u.id_perfil FROM usuario U INNER JOIN perfil P ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.usuario='"
                + usuario + "' AND u.contrasena='" + contrasena + "'";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                if (d_lgn.getContrasena().equals(contrasena)) {
                    resultado = true;
                } else {
                    resultado = false;
                }

                d_lgn.setPerfil(rs.getString("id_perfil"));
                d_lgn.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
                d_lgn.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                d_lgn.setApellido(rs.getString("apellido"));
                d_lgn.setContrasena(rs.getString("contrasena"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: Logica_usuario.tableRegistros(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Nota: "Dato_login d_lgn" es para poder acceder a esa clase que contiene los getters y setters para guardar la información localmente y mostrarla mas rápido.

Mi sentencia SQL esta correcta?, estoy pidiendo el nombre del perfil en lugar de el id_perfil?, estoy comparando bien el usuario y contraseña?.

Ayuda por favor, sería bien recibida.

Comment: El if dentro del while lo puedes sacar porque ya pusiste la condición en el WHERE que la contraseña sea igual. Y en el SELECT si quieres que te devuelva el nombre del perfil por p.nombre.

Comment: asi: sSQL = "SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.contrasena, u.id_perfil, p.nombre AS perfil_nombre FROM "
       + "usuario U INNER JOIN perfil P u.id_perfil = p.id "
       + "WHERE u.usuario='" + usuario + "' AND u.contrasena='" + contrasena + "'";  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pregunta es para evitar inyecciones sql, supongo. Pues solo te falta comparar el usuario y la contraseña obtenida de la BD y lo que trajiste de la vista.

```
public boolean login(String usuario, String contrasena) {
    Dato_login d_lgn = new Dato_login();
    boolean resultado = false;

    sSQL = "SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.contrasena, u.id_perfil FROM usuario U INNER JOIN perfil P ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.usuario='"
            + usuario + "' AND u.contrasena='" + contrasena + "'";

    // Java 7 try-with-resources
    try (Statement st = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString("usuario").equals(usuario) && rs.getString("contrasena").equals(contrasena)) {
                resultado = true;
            } else {
                resultado = false;
            }

            d_lgn.setPerfil(rs.getString("id_perfil"));
            d_lgn.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
            d_lgn.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
            d_lgn.setApellido(rs.getString("apellido"));
            d_lgn.setContrasena(rs.getString("contrasena"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: Logica_usuario.tableRegistros(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    return resultado;
}
```

Así compruebas el valor de la vista con el valor de la base de datos. Ojo, comprobar usuario y contraseña, en ambos te pueden hacer inyección.

Comment: cambiaré a preparedstatement, gracias hermano!!.

Answer (score 1):

Es más simple, no hay que hacer JOIN, y solo mirar si hay algun registro que cumpla el WHERE o no hay registros para ese WHERE.

```
public boolean login(String usuario, String contrasena) {
    boolean resultado = false;

    sSQL = "SELECT u.nombre FROM usuario U WHERE u.usuario='"
            + usuario + "' AND u.contrasena='" + contrasena + "'";

    // Java 7 try-with-resources
    try (Statement st = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

        resultado = rs.next();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: Logica_usuario.tableRegistros(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Angel. Gracias por tu aporte... Me cuesta ver si hay alguna diferencia con la respuesta aceptada  que publicaron hace 4 meses. Si se diferencia en algo, ¿podrías [edit] tu respuesta para remarcarlo?